How to Avoid Infinite Loop When Setting Loader State with Axios Interceptors in React?
I'm working on a React application where I need to show a loader during API calls using Axios interceptors. However, I'm encountering an issue where setting the loader state to false after receiving a response causes an infinite loop.
Here is my code:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Home, About, Gallery, Packages, Policy } from './pages';
import './App.css';
import Layout from '../Layout.jsx';
import Loader from './components/Loader';

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
      console.log(config)
      setLoading(true)
      return config;
    }, function (error) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
      // setLoading(false)
      console.log(response)
      return response;
    }, function (error) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
              <Route index element={<Home />} />
              <Route path='about' element={<About />} />
              <Route path='gallery' element={<Gallery />} />
              <Route path='packages/:type' element={<Packages />} />
              <Route path='policy/:type' element={<Policy />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

The infinite loop only occurs when setLoading(false) is uncommented.
I implemented Axios interceptors to set the isLoading state to true when a request starts and to false when a response is received.
When setting setLoading(false) in the response interceptor, the loader enters an infinite loop of showing and hiding. This issue seems to be caused by continuous re-renders triggered by state updates in the interceptors.

Might be a bit of a long shot but I have a feeling this is what's happening: 1. You request something from inside your app. 2. The router gets unmounted because the loading state is set to true. 3. The loading state is set to false and the router gets remounted. 4. Since the router is remounted, the request is run again (presumably from inside a useEffect with and empty dependency array, right?) 5. The cycle repeats.

To me, it sounds like if you want to have a "central" place to handle the loading logic, you would have to fetch the data at this level and then pass it to your children with a global state or context. The reason being, you control exactly where the request is done and avoid the infinite loop error you're facing. You might want to consider using something like react-query for this.
